# CUDA error at cuCtxCreate: Launch failed

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, error, scene, system

I wanted to render a scene in Cycles Render and there was an error. I'm using a GTX 1050TI with 1898 Mhz (OC). I have 16GB Ram in my PC and used 8192MB Ram in Blender.
My Render performance is at 64 at "Start Resolution" and my sampling is at 128 (render).[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=CUDA%20error%20at%20cuCtxCreate%3a%20Launch%20failed

Comment: Whem I#m using CPU then it works